# Finding coordinates of a character?

Tags: android, textview, coordinates

I have a multi-line `TextView`. Is there a way to get the x coordinate of the pixel to the left of a character e.g. the 3rd character? In my case it will always be the 3rd character, but a general solution would be nicer.

I have the y coordinate of the pixel just above the character using:

```
Layout textViewLay = mTextView.getLayout();
int posY = textViewLay.getLineTop(0);
```

but the x coordinate has me stumped. Any ideas? I'm probably missing something really simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint tpaint = textView.getPaint();
tpaint.getTextBounds(text,0,2,bounds);
int height = bounds.height();
int width = bounds.width();
```