# draw a rectangle behind a specific part of text in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` inside a `layout` and I'd like to add a coloured rectangle behind the text that starts at position "`start`" and ends at position "`end`" . The text is on the same line. I just need to know how can I get start and end coordinates of the rectangle I'll need to draw.

e.g : " This is my text "  and I'd like to draw a rectangle behind "is my" .

I tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696265/finding-coordinates-of-a-character) but it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SpannableString and set BackgrouundColorSpan in desired areas.

```
SpannableString spannableString =new SpannableString("This is my text");
spannableString.setSpan(BackgroundColorSpan(R.color.colorAccent),5,9,SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
yourTextView.setText(spannableString);
```

Comment: I'm aware of that option. The problem is that I'll need to use that rectangle in an animation , that's why it has to be a separate View , not just some BackgroundColorSpan